# How to update an individual port tree in Freebsd ports?

Tags: freebsd, ports

I tried portupgrade -a more than 2 hours ago and it is still upgrading. Come to think of it, I didn't really need to upgrade the whole ports trees. The one I needed to update is pecl-APC which resides under www/. Could someone tell me how to update only that specific port? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use : portupgrade -R app_name